# How to do `npm update` without modifying package.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-update

I have couple of dependencies that they always need to be on the latest specific major version. So I added them to the package.json dependencies list like below:

```
{
...
  dependencies: {
    "A": "^12.0.0",
    "B": "^12.0.0",
    "C": "^12.0.0",
    ...
```

Lets say in *package-lock.json*, package **B** has version 12.2.2. A new version of package **B** arrives with version 12.3.0 and no updates for other packages exist.

When I do `npm update` the *package.json* file changes to below:

```
{
...
  dependencies: {
    "A": "^12.0.0",
    "B": "12.3.0",
    "C": "^12.0.0",
    ...
```

I don't want that to happen. I want *package-lock.json* and *node_modules* gets updated but package.json stays the same for package **B**.

I tried `npm update --no-save`, but that would only update *node_modules* and not the *package-lock.json*.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How come you want this? Do you have other dependencies you *don't* want this behaviour for? Is the lock file actually helpful to you here? Can you just revert the changes to the package file?

Comment: I want this to always happen. when I specify versions with tilda "^" and do `npm update` I don't want them to get locked on a specific version in my package.json. because if a second update arrives then `npm update` won't get the second update.
right now, everytime I want to do `npm update` I need to go and update package.json file as well.

Comment: That's not true, because ^12.3.0 still allows upgrades from there to anything below 13

Comment: Yea but it's not getting modified to "^12.3.0", it changes to "12.3.0" after `npm update`.

Comment: That's not what I'd expect. Do you have any specific NPM configuration settings?

Comment: As far as I can tell (e.g. `mkdir temp && cd $_ && npm init -y && npm i eslint@7.3 && jq '.dependencies.eslint' package.json && npm up eslint && jq '.dependencies.eslint' package.json`, which shows `"^7.3.1"` then `"^7.5.0"`) that's *not* what happens, either. Please give a [mre].

Comment: You were right, there was `.npmrc` file in the project with config `save-exact=true`. Thank you @jonrsharpe for your quick answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior was the `.npmrc` configuration file on the root of my project.

I changed the `.npmrc` file to below:

```
save-exact=false
```

`save-exact=false` is the default config.

Now with the fix, in my example, the package.json file should look like below after doing `npm update`:

```
{
...
  dependencies: {
    "A": "^12.0.0",
    "B": "^12.3.0",
    "C": "^12.0.0",
    ...
```